# Loop for nth-child and set style doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have  with class fade-in-row.
I want for each nth-child with fade-in-row class to have animation delayed by 0.25s.
I had this:

```css
.fade-in-row{
  animation: fadeDown 0.5s both;
}
.fade-in-row:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.fade-in-row:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
.fade-in-row:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.fade-in-row:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

But it's capped at 5. I can add more, but i need a lot of them.

I used google, and now i know about `querySelector`.
Now my code in OnLoad() (which is used in ) is this:

```js
for (let i = 1; true;i++){
    if (document.querySelector(`.green-text :nth-child(${i})`) == null) break
    document.querySelector(`.green-text :nth-child(${i})`).children[0].style.animationDelay = i/4;
}
```

And needed part of html is:

```
<div class="green-text">
    <div class="fade-in-row">
        <h1>Foo</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="fade-in-row">
        <h1>Bar</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="fade-in-row">
        <h1>Some text</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="fade-in-row">
        <h1>More Text</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

No errors in console but it doesn't work.

Comment: might SASS/LESS be an alternative where you can create those CSS declerations with a for loop?

Comment: Hi! I never heard about SASS/LESS so idk if i should use them :)
Can i use them if i'm hosting website with github pages?
Which one should i use if i can?

Comment: yes it is a free to use CSS pre-processor. You can compile SASS to CSS directly. You don't have to do it server sided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used ***[`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)*** event along with **[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**. You can trigger the animation on other events as well. Something like:

```js
function animateDelay() {
  const fadeInRows = document.querySelectorAll('.green-text .fade-in-row');
  fadeInRows.forEach((element, index) => {
    element.children[0].style.animationDelay = `${index * 0.25}s`;
    element.children[0].classList.add('fade-in-row-animated');
  });
}

window.addEventListener('load', animateDelay);
```

```css
.fade-in-row {
  /* Commented this ----> animation: fadeDown 0.5s both; */
}

@keyframes fadeDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.fade-in-row-animated {
  animation: fadeDown 0.5s both;
}
```

```html
<div class="green-text">
    <div class="fade-in-row">
        <h1>Foo</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="fade-in-row">
        <h1>Bar</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="fade-in-row">
        <h1>Some text</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="fade-in-row">
        <h1>More Text</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: rather use `addEventListener` instead of `onload` to append the event instead of overwriting existing ones.

Comment: Looks like the problem is what animation applies before `animation-delay` is added. So i need to leave class blank at start, then add animation-delay and then add `animation`. But animation has 3 paramanets, idk to assing 3 paraments. When i do `element.children[0].style.animation = fadeDown 0.5s both;` it errors.